# How to update a table cells from another table's columns with different conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let assume that I have two tables in my database as below:

Table 1 (current_prices): Which contains some stuffs and their prices and it updates one time per day:

```
# current_prices
| commodity  | price |
____________________
|  stuff1    | price1
|  stuff2    | price2
|  stuff3    | price3
|.           |
|.           |
|.           |
|  stuffN    | priceN
```

Table 2 (stat_history): Which divide stuffs in price ranges and keep the number of elements of each range for all days as below:

```
# stat_history
|   date    | range1_count | range2_count | range3_count
________________________________________________________
|  20200411 |       12     |      5       |      9
|  20200412 |       10     |      5       |      11
|  20200413 |       13     |      4       |      9
|  20200414 |       15     |      3       |      8
```

The content of `stat_history` table are generated from `current_price` contents at the end of the day.

Currently I use multiple **Update-Insert** (Upsert) queries to update my stat_history table as below:

```
insert into stat_history (date, range1_count)
    select now()::date , count(stuff) as range1_count from current_prices
        where 0 < price and price < VAL1
    on conflict(day)
        update set
            range1_count = excluded.range1_count

insert into stat_history (date, range2_count)
    select now()::date , count(stuff) as range2_count from current_prices
        where VAL1 < price and price < VAL2
    on conflict(day)
        update set
            range2_count = excluded.range2_count

..... (blah blah)
```

The question is:

**Is there any shorter, simpler or more efficient way to do this (In a single SQL query for example)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do conditional counts, using Postgres standard `filter` clause:

```
insert into stat_history (date, range1_count)
select 
    now()::date, 
    count(stuff) filter(where price >= 0 and price < VAL1) as range1_count,
    count(stuff) filter(where price >= VAL1 and price < VAL2) as range2_count
from current_prices
where price >= 0 and price < VAL2
on conflict(day) 
update set 
    range1_count = excluded.range1_count
    range2_count = excluded.range2_count
```

Notes:

- I adapted the logic that puts rows in the intervals to make them contiguous (in your original query for example, a price that is equal to `VA1` would never be counted in)
- with this logic at hand, you might not even need the `on conflict` clause

Comment: Does it updates `range2_count` and `range3_count` in the first executaion? I guess don't, because there is no conflict at the first execution each day. Am I right?

Comment: @Abraham: it computes all counts at once, and tries to insert them in the table. If a record already exists, then all counts are updated.

Comment: Is the clause `where price >= 0 and price < VAL2` necessary? Why?

Comment: @Abraham: no it is not *strictly* necessary, that's just an optimization so the query only processes the set of rows that belong to the ranges. But if you remove it you get the same results.

Comment: Thank you. And may I ask you to please add a little more explanation about the reason which you said I might don't need the `on conflict`? I added this for cases which the script executes more than once accidentally. Because I need only one record for each day. How the logic can handle it?